# How do I fix my error running npm run dev?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack-dev-server, laravel-mix

I get an error when I run `npm run dev`. What am I doing wrong?

```
C:\laragon\www\GestionBAT                            
λ npm run dev
```

> @ dev C:\laragon\www\GestionBAT
> npm run development
>
> @ development C:\laragon\www\GestionBAT
> mix
>
> Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\alexi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-18T15_38_03_157Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\alexi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-08-18T15_38_03_282Z-debug.log

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "webpack": "^5.50.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your `package.json` for the scripts section.

Comment: "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },

Comment: here is my package.json i looked for error but not see

Answer (score 0):

"Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable." What does this mean?
Google translate says : "Specified path not found"

So when you run `npm run dev` it runs `npm run development` that in turn runs `mix`.

Are you sure `mix` runs normally in your terminal without this? That seems like the problem. Check that once.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is returning a non-zero status code so the problem is with the "mix" application, whatever that is, and not an NPM issue.